# Does the more time a function takes means its runtime complexity is larger?

Tags: performance, testing, timer, runtime

Is it wise to verify runtime complexity of code with timer tests?

For example:

```
x=very large input

timer start
foo(x)
timer end

print time
```

So if the time was 0 seconds then that means `foo` runs on O(n) or less and if timer is say 30-60 seconds, that means the runtime has to be larger than O(n)?

In general, does more time a function takes then that means it's runtime complexity is larger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Runtime complexity or **Asymptotic complexity** are part of **apriori analysis**. In simple these are theoretical measures of code.

for example,

```
funtion foo (){
    for (i=1;i++;i<n)
        do x;
}
```

According to above exmple,

Apriori (before running code) analysis says, its runtime complexity will be O(n), as loop will get executed n-1 times.

Suppose if we run this code, we found out that code is taking 1 min to execute.
Then we can conclude below things,

```
1. do() function is taking more time -- it is costly
2. Running complexity is O(n)
```

conclusion is running complexity is based on data structures and loops. they are not related to actual running time.

It doesn't matter if your code is taking 1 sec or 1 hr to execute, runtime complexity is fixed for a piece of code. Time is getting wasted somewhere in that function.

It is simple like, if you write a simple program for printing 1-n in a loop.

for us time complexity is always O(n) as long you are printing 1-n. but if your print command takes 3 sec to print a number then your program is taking high time to execute but it doesn't mean time complexity is O(n^2).

I hope you are clear now :)

Comment: So it's possible for even a code with a complexity of O(n^100) to run in 0 secs? Alternatively if we know for sure that all the operations of the function are very quick (like simple math operations) then will that help with estimating the complexity with a timer?

Comment: Yes. for "will that help with estimating the complexity with a timer?", you can have rough idea. Again don't try to mix up things(apriori analysis(runtime complexity) and posterior analysis(timer)). but yes if you know all operations time then you can have some estimates with timers.

Comment: One last question, if I have two functions that have the same input and they do similar things with this input, one I know for sure runs on O(n) but I don't know about the other one. If both take the same time to end, does that mean both are O(n)?

Comment: not exactly. maybe they both have O(n) or second has O(n^2) or more or O(log n) or less, but it is using some efficient method to run faster. Though runtimes are same but that doesn't guarantee about same runtime complexity.